# How can I conditionally transform an XML node, without omitting its' instances outside of this condition?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-1.0

I am transforming all  `<p>`  tags and renaming these nodes to  `<Body_Text>`, on the condition that they are *within* the  `<body>`  element (using  `xsl:if`).

My code *is* doing this, however it is omitting all  `<p>`  elements that are outside of the  `<body>`  element, which I *don't* want it to do.

---

Here is the XML to be transformed:

```
<root>
<p>asdf</p>
<body>
<p>asdfasdf</p>
<p>asdfasdf</p>
</body>
<footer>
<p>asdf</p>
</footer>
</root>
```

...here is the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity rule -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Body_Text -->
    <xsl:template match="p">
      <xsl:if test="parent::body">
        <Body_Text>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Body_Text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and here is the undesired result (omitting all  `<p>`  elements that are outside of the  `<body>`  element, which I *don't* want it to do):

```
<root>
<body>
<Body_Text>asdfasdf</Body_Text>
<Body_Text>asdfasdf</Body_Text>
</body>
<footer/>
</root>
```

This was tested at http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php.

---

**This is the desired result, which I am *not* getting**:

```
<root>
<p>asdf</p>
<body>
<Body_Text>asdfasdf</Body_Text>
<Body_Text>asdfasdf</Body_Text>
</body>
<footer>
<p>asdf</p>
</footer>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `xsl:if` is needed -- just specify proper template patterns.

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="body//p">
  <Body_Text><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Body_Text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <p>asdf</p>
    <body>
        <p>asdfasdf</p>
        <p>asdfasdf</p>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <p>asdf</p>
    </footer>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <p>asdf</p>
   <body>
      <Body_Text>asdfasdf</Body_Text>
      <Body_Text>asdfasdf</Body_Text>
   </body>
   <footer>
      <p>asdf</p>
   </footer>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

The template pattern of:

```
 <xsl:template match="body//p">
```

causes this template to be selected for execution only on `p` elements that are descendents of a `body` element. All the rest nodes are copied "as-is" by the identity rule.

Comment: Great, thanks again @Dimitre! Could you please explain what it was about `<xsl:if test="parent::body">` that does *not* retain elements outside of the `<body>` element? ...and how that is different from `<xsl:template match="body//p">
`?

Comment: @IanCampbell: The template mathcing `p` in your code simply doesn't do anything (ignores, "deletes") for a `p` that isn't a child of a `body`. To correct this and still use explicit conditionals (which I `don't recommend), who need to use `xsl:choose` and in its body have separate `xsl:when` instructions for the two disjoint cases.

Comment: Ah ok, so `<xsl:if test="parent::body">` does nothing to elements not satisfying this condition, therefore *not* producing the desired result because it is *only* processing elements within the given condition. Thanks @Dimitre. And your solution is much simpler than using explicit conditionals, is this why you are saying it is bad, because it unnecessarily complicates the code?

Comment: @IanCampbell: Exactly -- code with conditionals is longer, more complex, less readable and understandable, more error-prone, less extensible and less maintainable. As a rule, I aim not to have explicit conditionals in my code.